# Add a new column based on values in another column

Tags: r

I'm using R-studio. I want to create a new column called intervention based on values of another column called period. So, if period is less than 0, then return 0. If period is > 0 then return 1, 2, 3, and son on. If period = 0, then leave empty. Below is my dataframe:

```
period<- c(-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
```

My desired output is:

```
newdf<-data.frame(period = c(-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),
              intervention = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newdf<-data.frame(period = c(-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
newdf$intervention = ifelse(newdf$period < 0 , 0, ifelse(newdf$period ==0, "",newdf$period))
```

Comment: Thanks Aashish. what if instead of leaving 0 empty, I want the 1 to start from 0. So, I'll end up with 0(1), 1(2), 2(3) and so on. The numbers in bracket are the new values. Any value less than 0 still be coded as -1 to infinity but value from 0 will be coded 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: in that case, you don't need 2 ifelse. You can retain value in if condition and add +1 in else condition. `newdf$intervention = ifelse(newdf$period < 0 , newdf$period, newdf$period+1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cumsum` on a logical vector to create the column, `replace` the value where the 'period' is 0 to blank (`''`)

```
library(dplyr)
out <- tibble(period) %>% 
    mutate(intervention = replace(cumsum(period > 0), period == 0, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `ifelse` and change the value 0 to `""` aftre, but if you insert a string your vector will became a character one. Maybe is better to change `""` with `NA`. So you can use the new column as a number vector

```
period<- c(-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
intervention <- ifelse(period<0,0,period)
intervention[period==0] <- ""
#probably better
intervention[period==0] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks Elia. What if instead of leaving 0 empty, I want the 1 to start from 0. So, I'll end up with 0(1), 1(2), 2(3) and so on. The numbers in bracket are the new values. Any value less than 0 still be coded as -1 to infinity but value from 0 will be coded 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this what you want: `intervention <- ifelse(period>=0,period+1,period)` ?In this way the numbers <0 will remain the same and 1 will be added to those> = 0

Comment: Brilliant. That works fine. Thanks ever so much Elia.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

period %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(intervention = ifelse(value < 0, 0, ifelse(value == 0, "", 
                                                    value)))

# A tibble: 24 x 2
   value intervention
   <dbl> <chr>       
 1   -12 0           
 2   -11 0           
 3   -10 0           
 4    -9 0           
 5    -8 0           
 6    -7 0           
 7    -6 0           
 8    -5 0           
 9    -4 0           
10    -3 0           
# ... with 14 more rows
```